# Passing parameters to click events

Tags: asp.net

How do I pass parameters to click event handlers from dynamic link buttons? I don't want to use command events. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ViewState. Store your parameters in ViewState and then access them in your event which is handled:

```
link += new.EventHandler(this.link_Click);
ViewState[Param 1]="Value";
```